# Quantized input and output with TFLite in TensorFlow 2.0.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, mnist, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I'm trying to perform post-training integer quantization using TFLiteConverter in TensorFlow 2.0.0 as described in the [post-training integer quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant) tutorial. Unfortunately, my input and output are still in float32:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()

quantized_model = tf.lite.Interpreter("mnist_model_quant.tflite")
quantized_model.get_input_details()
```

Output:

```
[{'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 8,
  'name': 'flatten_1_input',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'shape': array([ 1, 28, 28], dtype=int32)}]
```

Prior to tf 2.0.0, when using tf 1.15.0 I was able to get a fully int8 quantized model. How can I achieve this with TF 2.0.0?

Testing Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17uoSGPQLhAqAfrIGyRm8Zkr2E8ig3-X0

Comment: As this has not been answered successfully, I've escalated as a GitHub issue, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40681